# Retrieve multiple data from Firebase to my Android applciation

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an application that needs to retrieve a multiple data from my Firebase database and store the data in my application.

> This is my database structure, and I want to retrieve all data from 1 upto the last number as well as retrieve the data inside each number.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all those objects under `Destination` node, you need to iterate over the `DataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference destinationRef = rootRef.child("Destination");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
destinationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

If you are using a model class, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference destinationRef = rootRef.child("Destination");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            YourClass yourClass = ds.getValue(YourClass.class);
            Log.d(TAG, yourClass.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
destinationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Hi Gay Marist! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Sir, do u have any idea how to add checkbox in this data?

Comment: In order to follow the rules of this community,  please add another fresh question so me or other users can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and changed according your database name and etc.

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRvData;
private DisplayAllData allDataAdapter;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private TextView mTvEmpty;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
private List<User> mUserList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_data);
    initView();
}

private void initView() {
    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("usersDb/UserTable");

    mRvData = findViewById(R.id.rvData);
    mTvEmpty = findViewById(R.id.dlTvEmpty);
    mRvData.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mUserList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = dataSnapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                mUserList.add(user);
            }
            allDataAdapter = new DisplayAllData(DisplayActivity.this, mUserList);
            mRvData.setAdapter(allDataAdapter);
            allDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (mUserList.isEmpty())
                mTvEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                mTvEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

more information refer this link
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-realtime-database-crud/